# Sending and initializing data to another component with vue 3

Tags: vue.js

what I want to do is to send a value to the file "Notification.vue" when the button is clicked in the `hello word` file and I want to show `Notification`

[toastify](https://szboynono.github.io/mosha-vue-toastify/)

helloword.vue

```
<template>
        <button @click="toast">Toast it!</button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
        name: "helloword",
        methods: {
                toast() {

                }
        }
}
</script>
```

Notification.vue

```
<script setup>
import {createToast} from 'mosha-vue-toastify';

import 'mosha-vue-toastify/dist/style.css'

const props = defineProps({title: String})
const toast = () => {
        createToast(props.title)
}

</script>
```

Comment: It's not about Vue 3 but more of how to call child components from parent.

Comment: so how can i do this?

Comment: how's your helloworld and Notification components are conectected? which one is parent component?

Comment: main component "home"... what I want to do is send `Notification` data and show it on `home` page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a demo with Vue 2 for your understanding how components will communicate. You can migrate this in Vue 3.

Demo **:**

```js
Vue.use(VueToast, {
  // global options
});

Vue.component('notification', {
  props: ['title'],
  mounted() {
    if (this.title) {
      this.$toast.open({
        message: this.title,
        type: "success",
        duration: 5000,
        dismissible: true
      })
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: null,
  },
  methods: {
    toast: function() {
      this.title = 'Welcome!'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-toast-notification@0.6/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-toast-notification@0.6/dist/theme-sugar.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toast">Toast it!</button>
  <notification v-if="title" :title="title"></notification>
</div>
```

Comment: why post an answer using vue2 when the question asks for vue3?

Comment: @Bravo Author was looking for the approach. It was not about the Vue version at all.

Comment: Still - vue2 isn't 100% compatible with vue3 :p